# Mandatory scope in login with Google through Firebase SDK in javascript

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I am building a login with Google feature in a React front-end using Firebase SDK. In particular, if the user is new to the system I make a call to my backend to register them in our DB. To do this, I need to make sure that the user's age is above 14 so I **need** to know their birthdate. Therefore, my code to authenticate with google starts like this:

```
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read');
provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile');
const googleRes = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(googleRes);
```

From here on, if the user accepts I can register them and life is good. However, when the popup is prompted, the user gets the option to decline sharing their birthdate, as shown in the attached screenshot. [[image: login popup with checkbox for requested scope]

Since this is a mandatory requirement for me, I need to either:

- force the user to accept it (either they login accepting the claim or they do not login at all)
- or check in my code whether they did accept it or not (that would allow me to inform the user of the problem or try to provide a solution)

Do you know if any of these are possible?

**Note**: If the user declines the scope, then the second time they attempt a login with google, they are not promped a checkbox anymore, but instead Google informs that the birthdate will be shared. This is what I would like to happen in the first place. I provide a screenshot for this case as well.[image: second login attempt after not allowing the checkbox the first time]

I tried adding additional scopes and checked the response object from the SDK but I did not find any additional information that allows me to know what case am I in, or if I do need to prompt the user for their birthdate.

Comment: man shame its not HTML cause all you had to do is add this  word -->
required
to the <input> tag and you would be done.

Comment: yes exactly! :(

Comment: Man I wish I knew what to tell you, I suspect there is an option somewhere in there to check that to render the required into the field for you, but there are a quite a few FB users on here someone will know i bet.

Comment: There is mixed information by default it sounds not possible but i think a couple posts have some ideas to try.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57486662/firebase-firestore-is-there-a-way-to-enforce-required-fields-for-all-documents